# set props.image as background image in react-js

Tags: reactjs, image, background

I'm in react-js. Say I've a child component which gets an image from the parent.

I can display this image in the child component as

```
<img src={URL.createObjectURL(props.image)}/>
```

I'm surprised I didn't find a way to set this image as the background of a div (in the child component)

```
    <div
    style={{ 
      backgroundImage: ???
    }}/>
```

I really appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You probably just forgot to add width and height to the div, so it doesn't display. Or you forgot to put image url inside url() in CSS.

Try:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${props.image})`, width:"200px", height:"200px"
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do `URL.createObjectURL` just `props.image` should work and to add image in background, use

```
<div
    style={{ 
      background: `url(${props.image})`
}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jainChetan81 and @kajgod. However, I found out the solution is:

```
style={{ 
  background: `url(${URL.createObjectURL(props.image)})`
}}
```

Just `url(${props.image})` doesn't work with me